# Azure Websites Orchard Memory Consumption

Tags: azure, orchardcms, azure-web-app-service

I have had my blog running on Orchard in Azure for, I dunno, a few months probably. All has been well. I have about 10 content items. It is a small site. I'm running it in Shared mode. Browsing the site is fine, it is fast and all is great. But today I have been trying to edit some posts and add some new ones. My per minute CPU usage is just going crazy and keeps crashing the site and hence I cant save anything. Pressing publish just destroys the site.

I'm not upgrading to reserved mode like it keeps recommending for a fucking little blog with about 3 viewers.

Any ideas why the cpu usage could be going so crazy?

Error logs are pretty much empty, occasional error from disqus but that is only when I am loading blog posts...

UPDATE 1:
Removed disqus just in case. Still failing miserably with massive loads to publish content items.

UPDATE 2: Kinda strange... error logs say A tenant could not be started: Default. Sequence contains more than one element. I think it is talking about routes.

at Orchard.Mvc.Routes.StandardExtensionRouteProvider.d__a.MoveNext() in c:\Users\sebros\My Projects\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\StandardExtensionRouteProvider.cs:line 24

Comment: Did you enable caching?

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be on publishing changes to items that have already been published. Could refreshing the cache be the problem?

Comment: I don't know. If you have clear repro steps, please file a bug.

Comment: Yeah I have been trying to find the exact steps to creating this extra long publish time that causes my site to crash but seems to just be totally random. Has been fine now for the last 10 posts. Kinda weird, I will keep an eye on things and hopefully find the root of the problem. Cheers anyway

Answer (score 1):

You should check that extensions monitoring is disabled. It creates lots of `FileSystemWatcher` instances in order to get dynamic compilation responsive to live files modifications but it's unnecessary in production environments.

Look at "Disabling the Dynamic Module Loader" section on this page: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation

Comment: Cheers for the reply, just a quick question: can you install modules still with this disabled?

Comment: Yes, modules will be loaded and optionally compiled (if the binaries are not present) when the app is restarted, which happens automatically when a module is added from the gallery.